# Displaying marker info on a pop-up window from the bottom of the screen on marker click

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I've noticed with the new Google Maps iterations that when one clicks on a marker, instead of an info window appearing on top of the marker, a window shows up at the bottom of the screen displaying a bit of information about the

[image: location of the marker.]

[image: information on this location]

This window can then be dragged up to show more as well as other controls. My question is, how can I replicate this behaviour in the Google maps activity in my own app? I am yet to find any code snippets that demonstrate how this is done as Google has not posted any instructions on implementing this new behaviour with maps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be implementing a bottom sheet which is a part of Design support library.

import the design support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

1.Create a class and extend it as BottomSheetDialogFragment. Create your desired layout and inflate it in the setupDialog() method.

```
public class MyBottomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
       super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
       View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet3, null);
       dialog.setContentView(contentView);
   }
}
```

2.Call your Dialog fragment in your onMarkerClick in your google maps.

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new MyBottomDialogFragment ();
bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
```